# Find intersection of two dictionaries, and alter object attributes at intersection

Tags: python, dictionary, object

There are two objects, an apple and an orchard, each with their own initial attributes given below:

```
class apple:
    def __init__(self, apple_id, orchard_id):
        self.apple_id = apple_id
        self.orchard_id = orchard_id
        self.found = false

class orchard:
    def __init__(self, id):
        self.id = id
        self.picked_apples = []
```

Sets of these objects are stored in their own respective dictionaries. Each dictionary is sorted based on their orchard id, which can be thought of as representing where the apple was picked:

```
apple_dict = {“1”: apple(1,1), apple(3,1), “2”: apple(5,2), “3”: apple(2,3), apple(4,3), apple(6,3), apple(7,3)}

orchard_dict = {“1”: orchard(1), “2”: orchard(2), “3”: orchard(3)}
```

The goal is to match each apple to the orchard it was picked from, and change the apple.found attribute to true once the operation is complete. Additionally, we want to add the apple object to its respective orchards’ list, orchard.picked_apples. Comparing the dictionaries is simple enough. However, the trouble I’m having is with altering the attribute of the apple objects once dictionaries are compared, as well as adding the apple objects to the orchard’s list. Any ideas how this could be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can compare orchard ids with apple.orchard_id like this and update picked_apples list when corresponding orchard is found:

```
class apple:
    def __init__(self, apple_id, orchard_id):
        self.apple_id = apple_id
        self.orchard_id = orchard_id
        self.found = False

    def __str__(self):
        return f"apple_id: {self.apple_id}, oid: {self.orchard_id}"

class orchard:
    def __init__(self, id):
        self.id = id
        self.picked_apples = []
    def __str__(self):
        return ",".join(self.picked_apples)


apple_dict = {"1": (apple(1,1), apple(3,1)), "2": (apple(5,2),), "3": (apple(2,3), apple(4,3), apple(6,3), apple(7,3))}
orchard_dict = {"1": orchard(1), "2": orchard(2), "3": orchard(3)}

for apples in apple_dict.values():
    for a in apples:
        if str(a.orchard_id) in orchard_dict:
            a.found = True
            orchard_dict.get(str(a.orchard_id)).picked_apples.append(str(a))

for o in orchard_dict.values():
    print(o)
```

Result:

```
apple_id: 1, oid: 1,apple_id: 3, oid: 1
apple_id: 5, oid: 2
apple_id: 2, oid: 3,apple_id: 4, oid: 3,apple_id: 6, oid: 3,apple_id: 7, oid: 3
```